# mat-icon css color style is not applying

Tags: css, angular-material, angular9, angular-material-6, angular-material-7

As a fresher in Angular.I have a doubt.In Angular 4, we have an md-icon tag from MdIconModule which was
after changed to MatIconModule in later angular version.

consider a code in Angular 4

**app.component.html**

`<md-icon>add_alert</md-icon>`

**app.componentn.css**

`md-icon.add-alert{ color : purple }`

In above code, the icon has been changed to purple from black.

But in Angular 9,

**app.component.html**

`<mat-icon>add_alert</mat-icon>`

**app.componentn.css**

`mat-icon.add-alert{ color : purple }`

The above code didn't change the color.And also we need to manually add the class in the tag to change
the color.

can anyone explain the cause

Comment: Can you post the full code or a demo in CodeSandbox?

Comment: https://github.com/techiesarav/angular-material-demo.git   it is an angular material demo project

Answer (score 0):

You can apply style to mat-icon like this way

```
::ng-deep{
   mat-icon {
        font-size: 24px;
        color: #3b86ff;
      }
 }
```

OR

```
.white-icon {
   color: white;
 }

 /* Note: If you're using an SVG icon, you should make the class target the `<svg>` element */
.white-icon svg {
  fill: white;
}


<mat-icon class="white-icon">menu</mat-icon>
```

Comment: Thanks for your explaination..But In angular 4, <md-icon> don't have any class and the css can be applied using the icon name like below. html :<md-icon>add_alert</md-icon> css: mat-icon.add-alert{ color : purple }. why the above code works?